# VW Golf 2012 runs fine but won't accelerate from park without giving it gas

Tags: vw, transmission, automatic-transmission, golf, parking

I was driving the car and suddenly trying to stop it (of course I pressed the brake). While the car was moving 5 KM per hour, I accidentally shift gear from D(drive) to  P(parking) and hard a 'gar' 'gar' sound twice. It is auto transmission car. After that I noticed when I starts my car and move gear from P to D then the car doesn't move automatically, I have to press the gas in order to move it. But before it was not like that; the car would move once I put the D transmission. Other than that everything works really well. Just wondering how can I fix it? Any response would really be appreciated. Thank you.

The transmission is a Volkswagen DSG 7-speed.

Comment: Yes, it is DSG transmission and 7 speeds. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. This is not the worst thing that could happen: https://www.golfmkv.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-52559.html

Comment: you may have a stuck caliper.  Have you noticed any odd smells?

Comment: Not really. One thing I noticed though; when I leave my leg from the brake(and change gear from P to D) I can see the engine rpm increased but the car doesn't move unless I hit the acceleration :( . Also When I change P to R (rear gear) the car moves immediately withtout hitting the acceleration.

Comment: Could the behavior be part of an auto-hill-hold?

Comment: Could be! How can I turn off the auto-hill-hold function? is it possible from the settings so that I can give a try? Thank you.

Comment: Is there an "auto hold" button on your 2012 Golf DSG: https://www.volkswagen.co.uk/technology/parking-and-manoeuvring/auto-hold

Comment: I don't have the auto hold option or button in the car. Any other suggestions?